# How to make a second Pagebreak?

Tags: sectioning

I want to keep my figures within the section they belong to. However, I currently have this problem: [image] There are 3 figures that are now within the next section.

I tried using \pagebreak and got the following result: [image]. There's still one figure left in the wrong section. How can I make the next break? if I try \clearpage I end up with too much unnecessary blank space.

Comment: Try using the \FloatBarrier command instead of \clearpage.  \FloatBarrier requires \usepackage{placeins}.

Comment: Thank you both. The duplicated subject link worked for what I needed.